# XSL duplicate info problem

Tags: xslt

Just trying out xsl and I've got one problem that just won't go away.  My style sheet code is this

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="Fighter">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <b>Name </b>    <xsl:value-of select="name"/> <br/>
    <b>AKA</b>      <xsl:value-of select="nickname"/> <br/>
    <b>Age</b>      <xsl:value-of select="age"/> <br/>
    <b>Height</b>       <xsl:value-of select="height"/> <br/>
    <b>Division</b> <xsl:value-of select="division"/> <br/>
    <b>Reach</b>        <xsl:value-of select="reach"/> <br/>
    <b>Stance</b>       <xsl:value-of select="stance"/> <br/>
    <b>Nationality</b>  <xsl:value-of select="nationality"/> <br/>
    <b>Training Camp</b>    <xsl:value-of select="camp"/> <br/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bout">
    <table width="100%" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td width ="10%"><xsl:value-of select="result"/></td>
            <td width ="10%"><xsl:value-of select="opponent"/></td>
            <td width ="10%"><xsl:value-of select="waywon"/></td>
            <td width ="10%"><xsl:value-of select="round"/></td>
            <td width ="10%"><xsl:value-of select="event"/></td>
            <td width ="10%"><xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
            <td width ="10%"><xsl:value-of select="location"/></td>
            <td width ="10%"><xsl:value-of select="notes"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
       <h1>LIST OF UFC FIGHTERS</h1>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

I want to get some info on a fighter displed and then show the fight record as below.  however it keeps on adding an extra line, as below.

> Name George St Pierre 
>  AKA GSP 
>  Age 30 
>  Height 5ft 10
>   in 
>   Division Welterweight 
>  Reach 76 in 
>  Stance
>   Orthodox 
>  Nationality Canadian 
>  Training Camp Tristar Gym
>
> George St Pierre GSP 30 5ft 10 in Welterweight 76 in Orthodox Canadian
>   Tristar Gym

Why is this info printing out twice?  I'm sure this is probably simple but it's really frustrating me.

Comment: can you post your sample XML?

Comment: Did you show us the whole stylesheet?  Is the XSLT you showed us wrapped in `<xsl:template>` tags?  If the document you're transforming isn't completely matched by templates, the XSLT processor will apply a trivial default template, basically just stripping the tags.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have apply-templates in template Fighter and no template for name, nickname, age etc - so XSL just copies text contented in this nodes - put this in the end of your XSL to avoid this and keep apply-templates there

```
<xsl:template match="*"></xsl:template>
```

This will put empty string for any tag not processed by other template

Comment: Seems like a hack to make up for sloppy template writing.  The OP should instead be explicit about which nodes to apply templates to, as in DSW's answer.

Comment: That is not true - when i want to apply template to foo, foo1 ... and i want to drop bar and bar1 - it is better to use this, and write templates for foo and foo1 ( without worrying about what will happen when i add foo2 and forget to write it evrywhere or i add bar2 )

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="Fighter">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <b>Name </b>    <xsl:value-of select="name"/> <br/>
    <b>AKA</b>      <xsl:value-of select="nickname"/> <br/>
    <b>Age</b>      <xsl:value-of select="age"/> <br/>
    <b>Height</b>       <xsl:value-of select="height"/> <br/>
    <b>Division</b> <xsl:value-of select="division"/> <br/>
    <b>Reach</b>        <xsl:value-of select="reach"/> <br/>
    <b>Stance</b>       <xsl:value-of select="stance"/> <br/>
    <b>Nationality</b>  <xsl:value-of select="nationality"/> <br/>
    <b>Training Camp</b>    <xsl:value-of select="camp"/> <br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bout">
    <table width="100%" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td width ="10%"><xsl:value-of select="result"/></td>
            <td width ="10%"><xsl:value-of select="opponent"/></td>
            <td width ="10%"><xsl:value-of select="waywon"/></td>
            <td width ="10%"><xsl:value-of select="round"/></td>
            <td width ="10%"><xsl:value-of select="event"/></td>
            <td width ="10%"><xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
            <td width ="10%"><xsl:value-of select="location"/></td>
            <td width ="10%"><xsl:value-of select="notes"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
       <h1>LIST OF UFC FIGHTERS</h1>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Fighter"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="bout"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```